# Power Query: Exclude Rows Based on User-Defined Set of Strings

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I am using Power Query in Excel for Microsoft 365.

In Excel, I have created a Power Query where one of the applied steps is to filter out rows where column **Description** contains as a substring any of a set strings. The strings to filter out are listed in a separate worksheet named **Exclude**. For example:

| String to Exclude |
| --- |
| Purple |
| Crimson |
| Cyan |

The table to be filtered (in worksheet **Input**) is as follows:

| Object ID | Owner | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Frank | Yellow legal paper |
| 2 | Sally | 4x Cyan sheets |
| 3 | Bob | Horseshoes |

The desired result (in worksheet **Output**) is:

| Object ID | Owner | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Frank | Yellow legal paper |
| 3 | Bob | Horseshoes |

If I were to hardcode the applied step that does the filtering, it would have the following M Language code:

```
let
    Source = ... ,
    ...
    #"Removed Duplicate Rows" = ... ,
    #"Removed Parts to Exclude" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Duplicate Rows", each not Text.Contains([Description], "Purple") and not Text.Contains([Description], "Crimson") and not Text.Contains([Description], "Cyan")),
in
    #"Removed Parts to Exclude"
```

However, end users need to be able to define the exclusion strings to use to filter rows out. This is the source of my desire to list these strings in a worksheet dedicated to that purpose instead of hardcoding them into the Power Query.

How may I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each not List.AnyTrue(let a=[Description] in List.Transform(Table1[String to Exclude], each Text.Contains(a,_))))
in #"Filtered Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you!
I needed to make only one small change to allow for the case of an empty list of exclude strings:
`Text.Contains(a,_ ?? "this is a string that should never appear in a description; it prevents a crash if the list of string to exclude is empty")`

Comment: Edited code to add a try...otherwise to eliminate error from null or zero row Table1. Thanks for pointing that out